# Does SQL ROLLBACK undo the enabling or disabling of triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, rollback

Let's say I have a SQL script that looks something like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.myTrigger ON dbo.myTable;

    --do something that requires the trigger to be disabled, but which might throw an error

    ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.myTrigger ON dbo.myTable;
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

If an error gets thrown in the "do something" part, there are two possible things that could happen:

1. Because the `ENABLE TRIGGER` statement is never hit, `myTrigger` remains disabled.
2. The `ROLLBACK` statement in the `CATCH` block rolls back *everything* that was attempted in the transaction, including the `DISABLE TRIGGER` statement, meaning `myTrigger` remains enabled.

I would intuitively expect 2) to be true, but a colleague of mine suspects that 1) is true instead, and you would have to manually re-enable the trigger inside the `CATCH` block. Neither of us could find anything on Stack Overflow or elsewhere about which interpretation is correct. So here's the question: does SQL's `ROLLBACK` statement roll back the enabling or disabling of triggers?

Comment: This would be easy enough to test; when you did, what did you notice?

Comment: Rather than asking us or your colleagues, why not give it a go and see what happens?

Comment: @ThomA boom boom

Comment: Only two things survive rollback i think: table variables and changes to external world. But yes, why waste time guessing, add a raiserror('test', 11, 11) in place of "--do something" and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested this myself, it seems that `ROLLBACK` does indeed undo the enabling and disabling of triggers. If I run the following script:

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
    DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.myTrigger ON dbo.myTable;

    RAISERROR('test', 11, 11);

    ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.myTrigger ON dbo.myTable;
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

Then run the following query:

```
SELECT is_disabled FROM sys.triggers WHERE name = 'myTrigger'
```

I get back "0", meaning that the `DISABLE TRIGGER` statement was rolled back.

Comment: btw, it might not be important, but one is supposed to check state of transaction instead of always adding ROLLBACK. The transaction might already be rolled back when the error occurs and rolling back again gives you another error. I usually do: IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN

Comment: More the point, rather than doing what @siggemannen says, just do `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, so the error will rollback either way.